# Understand is.na in SparkR column class

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

i have a question regarding `is.na` behavior in SparkR. The problem i have is I want to filter the data based on whether there is any NA in one column. However if I use `any(is.na(data$col1))` it will throw a warning of `is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'` but if i just use the top rows of the dataframe and do the exact the same thing there is no error and gives me the right answer`any(is.na(head(data)$col1))`. Below is the screenshot of my code:

[image]